# Как сделать градиентную рамку у текстового поля, поддерживающую border-radius?

Tags: html, css, градиент

Требуется, чтобы у текстового поля (`input[type="text"]` и `input[type="password"]`) была рамка, у которой на заднем фоне находится градиент, но вместе с тем должен работать `border-radius` (то есть, `border-image` не подходит). Задний фон текстового поля можно сделать непрозрачным. Желательно максимально короткое по размеру кода решение, без использования дополнительных элементов (только сам `input` и, может быть, `label`). Вот немного кода:

```
input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(blue, green);
}
input[type="text"]::after, input[type="password"]::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  right: -4px;
  bottom: -4px;
  left: -4px;
  background: linear-gradient(red, purple);
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```
<input type="text" name="test" id="test" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тега инпут нет псевдоэлементов, по этому без использования дополнительного элемента не обойтись.

```css
label {
  display: inline-flex;
  background: linear-gradient(blue, green);
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="text" name="test" id="test" />
</label>
```